# Creating an inflation calculator in PHP

Tags: php, cumulative-sum

Heres the code I have at the moment, its all working as intended, however, the cumulative total isn't working, and I'm positive I'm doing something absolutely stupid.

```
assume period = 20
assume inflation = 3
assume nightlycost = 100
assume nights = 7

$yearlycost = $nightlycost*$nights;
while ($period > 0) {
    $period = $period-1;
    $yearlyincrease = ($inflation / 100) * $yearlycost;
    $nightlyincrease = ($inflation / 100) * $nightlycost;
    $nightlycost = $nightlycost + $nightlyincrease;
    $yearlycost = ($yearlycost + $yearlyincrease) + $yearlycost;
}

Result:
Nightly Hotel Rate in 20 years: $180.61 - <?php echo round($nightlycost, 2); ?> correct

Weekly Hotel Rate in 20 years: $1264.27 - <?php echo round($nightlycost, 2) * 7; ?> correct

Total cost to you over 20 years: $988595884.74 - <?php echo round($yearlycost, 2); ?> incorrect
```

Everything outputs correctly and as expected, except for the yearly cumulative cost.  It should take the previous yearly cost and add that years cost+inflation.

Example: first year is 700, so second year should be 700 + 700 + 21 (21 is 3%, the inflation for that year).  Second year cumulative total is thus: 1421.  Third year will be 1421 + 721 (last years total) + 3% of 721.

Hopefully this is clear enough for you to see where I'm going wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Wouldnt you need to start your `$yearlycost` var like you are and then multiply it by 52 weeks?  right now that looks like a weekly cost ....  ` number of nights * nightly cost`

Comment: It's actually a holiday cost calculator - so the 7 nights is a user option, thats why I set it as nightlycost*nights, ie; this user spends 7 nights a year on holiday.

Comment: The yearly cost are always 700, not 721 – independent of how high the inflation is. If you want to incorporate into the products price, you should add the percentage to the nightly costs, thus they will get multiplied with the inflation costs already respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to understand where your code goes wrong, but my intuition is that the last line in your loop body should have a multiplication.

Basically, you have a base cost for period 0. Then you want to calculate the cumulative cost given inflation after X years. That cost is (pseudocode)

```
base = nightlycost + nights
infl = 1.03
cumulative = base + base*infl + base*infl^2 + base*infl^3 + ... + base*infl^periods
```

The last expression can be simplified to

```
cumulative = base*((1-infl^periods)/(1-infl))
```

(This holds according to Eq. 4 here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFormulas.html)

Example:

```
$base = 100*7;
$infl = 1.03; // 3% of inflation/year

$periods = 2;
$cumulative = $base * (1-pow($infl, $periods))/(1-$infl);
print "Cumulative cost after $periods is $cumulative\n";

// Let's try with three periods.
$periods = 3;
$cumulative = $base * (1-pow($infl, $periods))/(1-$infl);
print "Cumulative cost after $periods is $cumulative\n";
```

Output:

```
Cumulative cost after 2 is 1421
Cumulative cost after 3 is 2163.63
```